# Shortcuts not working in Eclipse Neon

Tags: eclipse

I'm running Eclipse Version: Neon.2 Release (4.6.2) on Windows 10.

Certain shortcuts like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>backspace</kbd> (which should delete the previous word) aren't working.

Under `preferances > General > keys` the setting is set as follows:

```
+----------+--------------------------+
| Command  | Delete the previous word |
+----------+--------------------------+
| Binding  | Ctrl+Backspace           |
+----------+--------------------------+
| When     | Editing Text             |
+----------+--------------------------+
| Category | Text Editing             |
+----------+--------------------------+
| User     | U                        |
+----------+--------------------------+
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Closing and opening the project fixed it.

Comment: I try several ways in stackoverflow, but only solution works

Comment: Unfortunately, this simple solution didn't work for me. Nor did Ad Infinitum's solution. Unchecking the option to show the welcome screen on startup and restarting Eclipse ([Vaibhav Pallod's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66604662/2274035)) worked

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution for me was to Restore Defaults in Preferences - General - Keys.

If you assigned some custom bindings it is possible that something went awry.

Answer (score 2):

After the solutions presented here and the other similar questions don't work for me, i removed the `.metadata` and `.recommenders` file in the Eclipse Workspace and restart the Eclipse, i am able to use my shortcuts again.

Please note that if you remove these files, you will lose your customized shortcuts and some other configurations as well. It means be careful when you are applying my solution.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Neon.1a Release (4.6.1), I too have experienced the problem of Ctrl + o (to list the members )and Ctrl + d (to delete a line of code) not working, I tried closing and starting the eclipse but that didn't help. I've noticed an option named 'Restart' in the File menu. Choosing the option restarted the eclipse and the shortcuts involving Ctrl key started working as before.

Answer (score 2):

I was finding about the welcome screen, but I disabled it, and apparently that was causing the issue everytime, because Ctrl+Shift+Right/Left worked with this all shortcuts worked fine, after disabling it. In Neon or other explise IDE versions, the welcome screen has an "Always show Welcome at startup" box you can uncheck, in the lower right corner of the welcome screen when it appears. After unchecking it, selecting words worked and all shortcuts start working again.
Thanks for your upvotes, this solution might help you!